# How to specify entity mappings in JPA 2.1?

Tags: java, jpa, orm

A correct starting tag for the entity mappings file for JPA 2.0 was

```xml
<entity-mappings version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd">
```

What are the required corrections for JPA 2.1?

I tried

```xml
<entity-mappings version="2.1" xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm">
```

But this gives the error:

> No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document.

Comment: that is a starting tag for JPA 1.0 not 2.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per what the JPA 2.1 spec says perhaps ;-) or the [docs of a JPA 2.1 implementation that tells you](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/jpa/metadata_xml.html)

Change java.sun.com to **xmlns.jcp.org**

Change orm_1_0 to **orm_2_1**

Change version="1.0" to **version="2.1"**

Comment: Thanks. Especially for the link

Comment: Link is broken :-(

Answer (score 6):

According to [official documentation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr338/index.html), section **12.3 XML Schema**:

```
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm
      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
      ...
</entity-mappings>
```

Answer (score 1):

For version 2.1 the following is working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence version="2.1"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
```